# Solr to Return respponse as a document or Rich text

Tags: hadoop, solr

I am new to Solr and below is my requirement in Solr
I have loads of emails stored in text format (semi-structured).
using Solr I have to index these documents when I am searching for a particular string (could be name) Solr should return the entire matching document/s as a response.
Kindly let me know how to do this in Solr. Is it advisable to store indexes in HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Solr can store original representation of the field with *stored* flag. So, you could store your text format in a field and then index it, or split it and index in multiple fields.

However, you may be better off storing those documents outside of Solr and structure content in Solr specifically for searching. Then, your middle-ware combines results returned from Solr with original documents stored somewhere.

The bigger emails are, the better it is for you to store them outside of Solr.